# How to display dynamically carousel images with JSON laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, carousel, laravel-blade

So I have this bootstrap 4 carousel div

```
 <div class="firstHalfRoomPagePart">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @foreach($room_data as $key => $r)
              <div class="carousel-item {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <img src="{{ $room_data ->images[0]}}" class="d-block roomImages" alt="...">
              </div>
              @endforeach
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
</div>
```

where in **carousel inner** I am trying to get the images dynamically to display them in my view.

I am trying to get the json from here:

```
 "images": [
         "/img/room_img/subbuteo_1.jpg",
         "/img/room_img/subbuteo_2.jpg"
      ],
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Where do you get the JSON from?

Comment: Can't you just `json_decode($json)` and pass it to the blade?

Comment: @shaedrich from my resources folder

Comment: What is the reason for using `$room_data` again inside the `foreach` loop? Don't you think it should be `$r->images`?

Comment: @saiyanPrince yes I missed that, and replaced it

Comment: @saiyanPrince but still r->images gives me an error

Comment: Can you give me the output of `dd($room_data)`?